# Highcharts Bubble Chart with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Please see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8rbmG/

The issue is that I'm trying to add dynamic data for Bubble Chart in Highcharts. I couldn't find any examples for it.
The data should be like : `data: [[97,36,79],[94,74,60],[68,76,58],[64,87,56],[68,27,73],[74,99,42],[7,93,87],[51,69,40],[38,23,33],[57,86,31]]` ie, arrays inside an array (from their sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bubble/

But when I try to achieve the same, the chart doesn't get plotted. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the way I'm providing data. Also, I'm getting this error :

> Uncaught Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19

which is : http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in the format of:

```
{
  "Month": "Dec", // x category
  "Cost": "978033", // x value 
  "Profit": "101661",  // y value
  "Revenue": "769755" // radius of bubble
}
```

When you provide x axis categories, internally `Highcharts` plots these at axis ticks:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....
```

So you have a situation where it's trying to draw categories starting at 0, but then plotting x data starting in the 100s of thousands, hence the `Too many ticks` error.

So did you want months or cost on the xaxis?  Here's [cost](http://jsfiddle.net/8rbmG/1/) and here's [months](http://jsfiddle.net/8rbmG/2/).

Comment: Wonderful! I need to learn to understand the errors. Thanks a lot!